# Completely dynamic URLs in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm building an online store based on CodeIgniter. I'd like URLs to look like this?

```
http://example.com/[product-category]/[product-name]
```

The thing is there are also non-product pages like `/checkout/step-1` and these still have to work.
What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Routes that you define in your routing config file (application/config/routes.php) are obeyed in the order that they are defined. If you put in your more specific routes first, then a generic catch-all route can be employed at the end.

```
$routes['checkout/step_(\d+)'] = 'checkout/step_$1';
// calls the checkout class, step_x method

$routes['(.*)/(.*)'] = 'product_class/product_method/$1/$2';
// calls the product class, and product method, passing category and name as parameters
```

The disadvantage to this approach is that you will have to define all of your routes in this file, even the ones that map directly to controller/action. A better approach might be to make your product routes start with 'product', so that they looked like this:

> http://example.com/products/[product-category]/[product-name]

With this approach you can define a routing rule that will only be applied to products like this:

```
$routes['products/(.*)/(.*)'] = 'product_class/product_method/$1/$2';
```

This is better because it does not force you to define concreate routes for every controller/action combination in your site.

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

Answer (score 3):

in application/config/routes.php, e.g.

```
$route['checkout/(:any)'] = "checkout/test_controller_method/$1";
```